# Apache config - https:// shows default SSL site with other domains on same server

Tags: apache, apache2, lamp

I need help with my Apache2 config.

I have some sites hosted on this server that are not SSL and one site that is SSL.
The problem is that entering https:// of any site hosted on the server will bring up the SSL hosted site with a certificate error.

How can I prevent this site from showing?

```
 <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
 NameVirtualHost *:443
 <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin miked@********.ca
    ServerName www.********.com
  CheckSpelling on
  CheckCaseOnly on


    DocumentRoot /var/vhosts/********.com
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All


    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/vhosts/*******.com>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

 LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined


    LogLevel error

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/*******-ssl_access.log combined env=!chat
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/*******-ssl-error.log


    #   SSL Engine Switch:
    #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
    SSLEngine on

    #SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt


    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/lubrigard.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/digicertCA.crt

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

 </VirtualHost>
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: What, there's no apache config experts here?

Answer (score 2):

9 months too late, I know, and I'm by no means an apache config expert, BUT-

I think the real solution to this problem is to get an additional IP address assigned to your server, and for the SSL vhost to listen only on that IP address.

Since, at least in regular applications (that is if you're not prepared to shun Windows XP users and below with IE 7 or 8 using *Server Name Indication* see [here](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)) a separate IP address is needed for each SSL certificate, because the handshake occurs before the host name is passed along, and therefore only the IP address is given by the client, there's no other clean way around this, because a host name mismatch will take place by the time anything else could be processed in the vhost entry, and visitors can see for which domain name the SSL certificate is actually valid.

You CAN however, once people have clicked "agree" or "add exception" to get past the warning, add a block like this to your SSL vhost, to redirect people to the appropriate domain. Only tested this for the domain name itself, not for pages or directories within it. (Taken partially from the first example given [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html))

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^(www\.)?********\.com [NC]
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(.*)$
      RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://%1/$1 [L,R]
  </IfModule>
```

...where the asterisks represent your domain name that *has* ssl. This should rewrite all other requests to their HTTP equivalents, whilst leaving requests to the ssl domain untouched.

If you can't get another IP address, and depending on your visitors, perhaps SNI is the way to go.

Maybe the folks over at Serverfault will know more?

Comment: 9 months too late but the problem still persists.  I think you are right however.  I dont think its possible to have it both ways.